# How to execute Cucumber steps in a specific order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am creating some specs using cucumber. The first one is checking a user login and the second one is checking specific things that a user would have to be logged in to see. Therefore i want Cucumber to run the steps where the user login is the first file to run. Is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally specific execution order is discouraged to encourage make each scenario complete, atomic.  Because passing states between test scenarios is not a good design. This is very valuable when troubleshooting or investigating test failures.

You can alter your feature to include a Background step for login. Alternatively, because cucumber sorts your feature files before execution, you can name your files in a specific order.